# pandas: compute % change between 2 columns, without rounding

Tags: python, pandas

I want to compute the percentage change in value between 2 columns like below

```py
df['change' ] =100*(df[df.columns[1]]-df[df.columns[0]])/df[df.columns[0]]
```

However I noted when the change values are very small like 0.001, Python round them to 0.

I want the exact values. Thank you

Comment: Can you provide an example? If values around 0.001 are rounded to zero, it is likely due to the way your output is displayed rather than the way they are stored in pandas.

Comment: check what this returns, and increase if needed with `pd.set_option("display.precision", some_higher_value)`: `pd.get_option("display.precision")`

Comment: embed a sample csv in your question (in raw CSV text format, not in dataframe format). and also give a sample dataframe output with the expection you want.